# How to let VS Code intellisense recognize new methods appended to existing class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I'm trying to define new methods on the class CanvasRenderingContext2D (which is the context object of the canvas element). For example,

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.dot=function(x, y) {
    ....
}
```

would be a new method that draws a dot with a certain style at the (x, y) coordinate (the exact code inside the function is irrelevant to my question here). My question is, how do I make VS code intellisense recognize that this is now a new method of CanvasRenderingContext2D? I've tried things like

```
/**
 * Draws a dot at the (x, y) coordinate
 * @memberof CanvasRenderingContext2D#
 * @param {number} x 
 * @param {number} y 
 */
```

but it doesn't work, and when I write down an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D, still only the original members are shown in intellisense. How do I make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem that nobody has an answer; in that case let me give a partial answer for those who might have the same demand. One could create a new lib.es6.d.ts file inside the project folder, and then add

```
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasPathMethods {
    dot(x:number, y:number):void;
}
```

to declare the new dot method; this would be enough to let intellisense to show it after any instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. However, it is not exactly a complete answer, since one cannot go to the actual definition of the dot method (using "go to definition" will only go to the said .d.ts file, not where the code actually is).

Even if I rewrite the entire project using TypeScript instead of JavaScript, I still cannot find a way to fix the problem with "go to definition". I can, however, put the declaration as close to the actual code of the method as possible, so that "go to definition" practically works, even though not technically.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use a custom @typedef like this:

```
/**
 * Draws a dot at the (x, y) coordinate
 * @param {number} x 
 * @param {number} y 
 */
const dot=function(x, y) {
}
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.dot = dot;

/** @typedef {CanvasRenderingContext2D & { dot: dot }} MyCanvasRenderingContext2D */

/** @type {MyCanvasRenderingContext2D} */
const o = new CanvasRenderingContext2D();
o.dot();
```

Comment: The main drawback of your solution is that you'll have to declare manually above each instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` as `MyCanvasRenderingContext2D`. However, it does solve the problem of "go to definition", and I'll give you a vote for that (you may not see it though, I don't have enough rep).